# WPF - Listview updating very sporadic

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, synchronization

I have a WPF program with two listviews which display information from two different observable collections. These observable collections are updated on a timer which fires every second.

For some reason, these listviews do not update when the data collection is updated... they will update occasionally but there is no guarantee that it will ever happen. I can run the whole program for 10 minutes and have nothing displayed... There are no databinding errors in the output window, either. In fact, if I populate the collection during startup, to test the binding, it is all displayed without problems. It's only when I am adding items dynamically during the execution of the program that there is a problem.

When trying to debug it is impossible to follow the program because for some reason I've got a whole load of worker threads running which I never defined or asked for:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0XB3.png

I think these extra threads might be part of the problem. Is there an easy way in C# to define a function as threadsafe like the synchronized keyword in Java?

EDIT:

```
JFifoErrorCollection.Add(errorData); 
JFifoList.Items.Refresh(); 
break;
```

EDIT #2: I have solved this issue.. I was using a System.Threading.Timer which didn't run on the UI thread. Changed to System.Windows.Forms.Timer and now it works perfectly.

Comment: Is your ListBox bound to a `List` or `ObservableCollection`? And can you post the code that updates the ListBox?

Comment: @Rachel 
    JFifoErrorCollection.Add(errorData);
    JFifoList.Items.Refresh();
    break;

That's the way I add to the collection which is of type ObservableCollection.

Could it possibly be due to the worker threads being the ones adding to the collection, meaning the collection changed event is not raised in the Main/UI thread? The main thread never seems to enter that function.

Comment: @Luke, an easy to test to see if the collection changed event is not raised in the UI thread is to create a method that Adds to the collection but ensures it invokes itself on the Dispatcher's thread.  If you see your updates, you know that's your issue.  If you need an example, let me know.

Comment: @Josh I have fixed the issue now. I was using the wrong kind of Timer... It would be useful to know how to ensure a function is invoked on the dispatcher's thread, though. If you could provide example code I would be very grateful.

Comment: No problem.  Here's a link that uses extension methods for dispatching.  You should be able to get everything you need here:    http://blog.decarufel.net/2009/03/good-practice-to-use-dispatcher-in-wpf.html.

Comment: WPF has its own timer for that: DispatcherTimer

Comment: You should answer this question and accept it so it can be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the WPF built in [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx).

Comment: Solved this problem a long time ago with System.Windows.Forms.Timer, but I will use DispatcherTimer in future. Thanks.